# Delete a line in a file with input of the user

Tags: file, python-3.x

Lets say i have a file called test.txt
In the file, i have the following data:

```
Mark,19,accountant
Sebastian,24,Truck-Driver
Mustafa,23,Police
```

Lets say, with just knowing the Name of the persons in the file, how can i delete the complete line with just the input of the name?
I know how to do it with entering the complete data "Mark,19,accountant" but what i would like to do, is delete the complete line if it contains Mark

Do you guys have any good idea on how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the line containing "Mark" from test.txt:

$ sed -i  '/Mark/d'  test.txt